# Understanding nested includes with LINQ and EF Where clauses

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm new to .NET and LINQ/EF and using Blazor. I have the following set up. There's no direct relationship between an `Order` and the `Membership` table. I have to go through the User's collection of `Memberships`.

What I'm trying to return is a list of Orders from User's who are active Members, but my query (shortened for brevity) isn't working and is returning all Orders regardless of the User's Membership status. Any help?

```
public class Order
    {
      public int OrderId get/set
      public string UserId get/set
      [NotMapped]
      public User User get/set
    }

public class Membership
{
  public int MembershipId get/set
  public string UserId get/set
  [NotMapped]
  public User User get/set
  public MembershipStatus MembershipStatus get/set
}

public enum MembershipStatus
{
  Active,
  Cancelled,
}

public class User 
{
  public virtual ICollection<Membership> Memberships get/set
  public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders get/set
}

public async Task<List<OrderDto>> GetOrders()
{
     return await _dbContext.Orders.Include(x => x.User)
                                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Memberships.Where(x => 
                                       x.MembershipStatus == MembershipStatus.Active))
                                    .Select(orderDto => new OrderDto 
                                    {
                                      // mapping properties
                                    }).ToListAsync();

}
```

Comment: Well, your code says, in plain English: "Get all Orders, Include all users, then include memberships where membership status is active."

Comment: To get a specific set of orders, you'll have to filter your orders first.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, okay, but how?

Comment: Something like `Orders.Any(x => x.Users.Where(y => y.Memberships.Any(z => z.MembershipStatus.Active)`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Yeah, that's wrong too.  You have to switch between `While` and `Any`.  Something like `Orders.Where(x => x.Users.Any(y => y.Memberships.Where(z => z.MembershipStatus.Active);`

Comment: What is users? the table? or do you mean the user property on Order?

Answer (score 3):

First off, remove `[NotMapped]` attribute from `Order.User` property, otherwise it cannot be used as navigation.

Second, if you are going to use projection query (`Select`), then remove all these `Include` / `ThenInclude` because they are for [eager loading of related entity data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) when querying full entities, and are simply ignored (have no effect) for projection queries.

Finally, whether you use projection or entity query with (filtered) includes, apply desired filter on root entity using regular `Where` (filtered includes filter the content, not the container).

In your case, something like

```cs
var query = _dbContext.Orders
    .Where(o => o.User.Memberships.Any(m => m.MembershipStatus == MembershipStatus.Active))
    .Select(...);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the AsNoTracking (and even the .Select if I remove the AsNoTracking), 'bool' does not contain a definition for AsNoTracking...
                                        .Where(p =>
                                                p.User.Memberships.Any(x => x.Status == MembershipStatus.Active
                                        )
                                        .AsNoTracking()
                                        .Select(p => new OrderDto
                                        {
                                            OrderId = p.OrderId,

Comment: Update. I figured it out using LINQ instead of EF nav properties. The data is just far simpler to query that way.

Comment: Not using navigation properties to perform the joins in L2E query is like not using one of the best things ORM provides over SQL. Speaking about simplicity, it's the opposite. As of errors, looks like you are putting some random operators w/o really understanding what they are for. `AsNoTracking` is the same as `Include` /  `ThenInlcude` - not needed for queries with `Select`. There is no way to get compile time errors if you use the sample query exactly how I wrote it in the answer. All it needs is `using System.Linq;` since it has no (and does not need) EF Core specific queryable extensions.